# When would you use -> ( ) in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Learning Swift and came across this example. What purpose does () -> in the first line serve and how would you use this in other simple examples?

```
func buildIncrementor() -> () -> Int {
    var count = 0
    func incrementor () -> Int {
        ++count
        return count
    }
    return incrementor
}

var incrementor = buildIncrementor()

incrementor()
incrementor()
```

Answer (score 6):

This is read as:

You are making a function `buildIncrementor` that takes no paramaters and returns a function

```
-> ()
```

that returns an int:

```
-> Int
```

Although I don't write this when I code, I like to think as if I'm reading it as:

```
func buildIncrementor() -> (() -> Int) {
    var count = 0
    func incrementor () -> Int {
        ++count
        return count
    }
    return incrementor
}
```

Note the additional parenthesis. This way it looks like what I'm saying: `buildIncrementor` returns another function. The function that `buildIncrementor` returns takes no parameters, and returns an `Int`.

Answer (score 4):

Empty tuple `()` is same as `Void`. You can read it as

```
func buildIncrementor() -> (Void -> Int)
```

a function `buildIncrementor` that return a type `Void -> Int`, that is a closure/function, takes `Void`(nothing) and return `Int`

BTW the function can be simplified to

```
func buildIncrementor() -> () -> Int {
    var count = 0
    return { ++count }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `buildIncrementor` function takes nothing and returns a function. And type of the returned function is `() -> Int` which means takes nothing returns an `Int`. Whenever arrow involved you are dealing functions or closures. Things on the left are input values and things on the right output values.

Answer (score 1):

The `buildIncrementor()` is returning a function as it's return type.

- `()` means - The function doesn't take any parameter
- `-> Int` means that it returns an Int as it's return type.

In total it is something similar to:

```
func buildIncrementor() -> (Void) -> Int
{
}
```

or in another way:

```
func buildIncrementor() -> ((Void) -> Int)
{
}
```

```
incrementor() // Will Return 1
incrementor() // Will Return 2
```

You can read more about returning a function in [Swift_Programming_Language/Functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your function is concisely written as:

```
func incrementor (var value : Int = 0) -> () -> Int { 
   return { return value++ }
}
```

The function `incrementor` accepts one argument `value` and returns `() -> Int` which is itself a function.  There is no need to name the internal function `incrementor`; you can simply use an anonymous 'closure'.  You can use this as

```
var inc_from_10 = incremenator (value: 10)
inc_from_10()    // 10
inc_from_10()    // 11
```

Functions that return functions are natural in a language like Swift where functions are 'first-class' (assignable to variables).  Combined with generic types and some sophisticated forms take shape.

```
// Return a function to test equality with an obj
func equate<T> (#pred: (T, T) -> Bool) (x:T) -> (T) -> Bool { 
   return { (y:T) in return pred (x, y) } 
} 

var equalToTen = equate (pred: ==) (x: 10)  // curry syntax

// Return a function to complement a predicate
func complement<T> (#pred : (T) -> Bool) -> (T) -> Bool {
  return { (x:T) in return !pred(x) }
}

var notEqualToTen = complement(equalToTen)

// Return a function conjoining two predicates
func conjoin<T> (#pred1: (T) -> Bool,  #pred2: (T) -> Bool) -> (T) -> Bool {
  return { (x:T) in pred1 (x) && pred2 (x) }
}
```

And you now start using these in, for example, sequence functions like `reduce`, `map` and `filter`.